# Sending Push Notification without accessing UDID

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, udid

I come to know that Apple started to reject apps that access UDIDs.
Then How can we send push notification without accessing UDIDs.
Is it possible? if yes, please help me to solve this problem.

thanks in advance.

Comment: you have nothing to do with UDID in order to send push notifications. Only relation between them is to keep track of unique devices (with UDID) and device tokens... Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Bartu Yes, now understood that UDID is not need for push notification

Comment: here is a reference for an alternative to UDID, https://github.com/blackpixel/BPXLUUIDHandler

Answer (score 7):

The device token (used by APNS) and the [UDID](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier) are two different things. They have nothing to do with each other.

You obtain the device token for push notifications in your app delegate's `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` method.

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) notes the following:

> The device token is different from the uniqueIdentifier property of UIDevice because, for security and privacy reasons, it must change when the device is wiped.