# Send Push To Specific iOS User

Tags: ios, push-notification, uniqueidentifier, udid, pushwoosh

I use PushWoosh for my push notifications.  I know with the API, it is possible to send to a specific user using devices identifier in the API.  However, I also know that developers can no longer access the UDID directly in iOS.  So, what are the steps that need to be taken in order to do this now?  I assume the UDID is gained somehow and a place-token # is created for it, and the app accesses that, but I'm a bit foggy on how to do all that.

Comment: `[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor` is the replacement for the deprecated `[UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier` UDID getter. Information on the deprecation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier) and information on the replacement is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15926188/2446155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send Push to specific user you don't need UDID. You should use token. Here is details about it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW12

So in short idea is that your App should get Token from APNS and send it to PushWoosh (I believe framework already do that for you). After this you can send Pushes to this device using this token.